# angular - get controller instance in service

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, bootstrap-modal, angularjs-controller

I got problem, I'm trying to get controller instance in my service:

```
myAppModule.service('modalService',
function ($modal, $controller) {
   var controller = $controller('ExperienceDetailsModalCtrl');
});
```

but I've got error:
TypeError: Cannot read property '$scope' of undefined

Is it possible to access controller (defined in another file) and pass it to modal?

My controller:

```
myAppIndexModule
.controller('ExperienceDetailsModalCtrl', function ($scope) {

});
```

Comment: Why do you want to access the controller inside the service?? generally, it's one way the controller uses the service and that's it, that's the goal of the service is to provide a service to the controllers

Comment: I would like to define all my modals in one place - I want to avoid passing a controller name and template each time, when I want to open a modal. So I supposed that create a service and functions for modals is a good idea. That's way. Maybe someone will propose me a better approach to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can't access controller scope in `service`, `factory` or `provider`. The data which you wanted to share should be placed inside a service. & make it available to other controller.

I think you do want to pass controller scope to `$modal` then you can achieve this by doing from controller itself.

```
$modal.open({$scope: $controller('ExperienceDetailsModalCtrl', {$scope: $scope}), templateUrl: 'abc.html'})
```

**Update**

You could do it like below

```
myAppModule.service('modalService',
function ($modal, $controller, $rootScope) {
   var scope = $rootScope.$new(true);
   $controller('ExperienceDetailsModalCtrl',{scope: $scope });
   //in scope now you will have ExperienceDetailsModalCtrl scope
});
```

Comment: That works fine. But I would like to do that in different way. I would like to define all my modals in one place - I want to avoid passing a controller name and template each time, when I want to open a modal. So I supposed that create a service and functions for modals is a good idea. Could you give me a advice, how to build it?

Comment: @Theo try my updated answer, its just suggestion may not work

Comment: Great! It works (almost :). When I define my controller it that way: controller('ExperienceDetailsModalCtrl', function () . But when I'm defining it like that: controller('ExperienceDetailsModalCtrl', function ($scope) - [with $scope] i got an exception: Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope.

Comment: But could you read comment above? It almost works - I updated my question - added controller code. When I try to inject $scope it doesn't work - exception: Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope. Without injecting scope it works...